# Print Writer and inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance

I am working on a program that operates like video rental store. I have two classes, DVD and Game, where Game extends DVD. I am working on writing a save and load to textfile methods, but hit a bit of a hiccup I can't seem to figure out.

Basically, if the item in the list is a game, i need to the print writer to get the type of system the game is played on and print it out to the file. As the Linked list is of DVDs I'm not sure how to get into the subclass Game. Here's my code for saving as a text file(it works fine if the item in the list is a DVD)

```
`public void saveAsText(String filename) throws IOException {
    {
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                new FileWriter(filename)));
        out.println(listDVD.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < listDVD.size(); i++) {
            DVD d = listDVD.get(i);
            out.println(d.getTitle());
            out.println(d.getNameOfRenter());
            out.println(d.boughtString());
            out.println(d.dBString());



            out.println("");

        }
        out.close();
    }
    }`
```

I've tried adding a bit of code to check if the item at index i if an instance of game, and then getting the system name, but crashed and burned pretty hard.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: "Crashed and burned pretty hard"...what does this mean?

Comment: Fancy showing us the "bit of code to check if the item at index i if an instance of game"? Now this might be because your code snippet is out of context, but it seems like you have a design scenario here you might want to avoid anyhow- could you tell us where `saveAsText(...)` exists, and where `listDVD` actually belongs to? Finally, a stack trace for the crash would be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question directly, to detect whether the item is actually a Game, you could use code like this...

```
if (d instanceof Game) {
  Game g = (Game) d;
  // access game functions here
}
```

...but that tends to be bad Java practice, because it doesn't take advantage of the polymorphism you're setting up. A better idea is to give DVD a method, like `writeTo(PrintWriter)`, which you could then override in Game to write the game-specific information. That way you can let every DVD subclass manage its own procedure for writing to a stream.

**Side note 1:** Maybe it's my fault for thinking of DVDs as movies by default, but I wouldn't have Game extend DVD, because that assumes that every Game *is a* DVD and that everything you can do with a DVD you can do with a Game. (`game.pause()`?) I'd instead have them both implement a common interface (RentalItem maybe?), or extend a common abstract class if there is code to reuse.

**Side note 2:** If you don't need `i` except to iterate through every item in a list, you can use a different type of `for` syntax instead:

```
for (DVD d : listDVD) {
  d.writeTo(out);
}
```

Comment: BRILLIANT! My problem with the instance of was trying to figure out how to assign the game variable to the item in the list.... cast it!

As for the design issue, I agree with you, but the design was passed down and I am not to change it.